# How do you get user input when running a bash script from a url?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, command-line

Consider this bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    read -p "Give me an answer ? y/n : " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) answer=true ; break;;
        [Nn]* ) answer=false ; break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
  done

if $answer 
  then 
    echo "Doing something as you answered yes"
      else 
    echo "Not doing anything as you answered no" 
fi
```

When run from the command line using :

```
$ ./script-name.sh
```

It works just as expected with the script waiting for you to answer **y** or **n**.

However when I upload to a url and attempt to run it using :

```
$ curl http://path.to/script-name.sh | bash
```

I get stuck in a permanent loop with the script saying `Please answer yes or no.` Apparently the script is receiving some sort of input other than **y** or **n**.

Why is this? And more importantly how can I achieve user input from a bash script called from a url?

Comment: You've redirected standard input for the shell already. That's where your script has just come from. So when bash tries to read *more* information from standard input it just gets `EOF` and spins.

Comment: Try `read -p "Give me an answer ? y/n : " yn < /dev/tty`.

Comment: well *cat script-name.sh | bash* would not work better than your curl command either...

Comment: use zentity ```

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps use an explicit local redirect:

```
read answer < /dev/tty
```

Comment: The problem I'm having with this answer is that the read happens before the echos explaining what to type happen...

Comment: @DavidSulpy try this: ``read -p "Enter answer:" answer < /dev/tty``

Answer (score 6):

You can run it like this:

```
bash -c "$(curl -s http://path.to/script-name.sh)"
```

Since you're supplying content of bash script to `bash` interpreter. Use `curl -s` for silent execution.